# Does Objective C have the equivalent of die()?

Tags: php, objective-c

In PHP there is `die()` in which it prints out whatever you put in the brackets in addition to killing a process.

What is the equivalent in Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `NSLog` followed by an `abort`:

```
NSLog(@"some error");    //print the error
abort();                 //kill the process
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How is `abort()` different from `exit(0)`, though?

Comment: @Max `exit` exits gracefully, like returning from `main`, but `abort` crashes the process.

Answer (score 0):

No - but you can always print out something before an exit(0);